# Deleted boot partiton to extend another partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, boot-repair

stupidly my disk setup was set up as sda1 as root, sda2 as boot, and sda3 as additional storage. I wanted to merge sda1 and sda3 partitions.

What I did was make a image of sda2 (boot), deleted it and merged sda1 and 3, assuming I could make another sda2 partition and just restore the image. Obviously this did not work. Is there any way I can make this bootable again?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you deleted the EFI partition with the bootloaders, or the partition mounted at /boot, with the kernels?  /boot partitions are optional unless needed because grub cannot read the root (encrypted, ... etc.)

Comment: Boot was mounted in sda1, EFI in sda2. It's fixed now but don't exactly know how... was playing around with the advanced settings in boot repair, was getting errors about EFI files, then booting in emergency mode, then another error while using boot repair using recommended repair... strange.

Comment: "*getting errors about EFI files*" - we need to know the verbatim errors and the context surrounding the errors to provide any insight into the errors

Comment: It would boot into efi shell with a list of different efi options, while boot repair advised on selecting a file along the lines of shimfx64, which was not available. For one reason or another it worked out when I ran boot repair again and reinstalled grub.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a USB bootable drive with Ubuntu (either a CD, USB stick, flash drive, SD card, etc.)

Make sure that you can boot this device by entering your BIOS and either enabling the USB device drive to boot and/or re-ordering the devices so that the USB device you intend to boot from comes first.

Then try the steps in this link.
https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-repair-the-grub-bootloader-using-a-ubuntu-live-usb-drive/